# Using exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, ipod, m4a

I try to export an audio file from the iPod-Library. I want to create with this iPod-Library file an new file. In the AV Foundation Programming Guide in chapter Reading and Writing Assets there is a little example. However this code doesn't work for me. 4 errors happens

```
Export Status 4 Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain 
Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" 
UserInfo=0x1edfa0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12124), 
NSUnderlyingError=0x1ebdc0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12124.)", 
NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

My code

```
AVURLAsset *objAvUrlAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[tempArray objectAtIndex:0]  options:nil];

NSLog(@"%s objAvUrlAsset %@", __FUNCTION__, objAvUrlAsset);

NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:objAvUrlAsset];

NSLog(@"%s compatiblePresets %@", __FUNCTION__, compatiblePresets);

if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A]) {


    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                                           initWithAsset:objAvUrlAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

    NSString * exportPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testTrack1.M4A"];
    NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

    exportSession.outputURL = exportURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
    exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;

     NSLog(@"%s export Session %@",__FUNCTION__, exportSession);

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: ^(void) {
        // export completed
        NSLog(@"Export Status %d %@", exportSession.status, exportSession.error);
    }];
    [exportSession release];
}
```

the nslog message

```
-[MyLocalMusicLibrary getAllTracks] objAvUrlAsset AVURLAsset: 0x1dd5a0, URL = ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-212958261728896866

 -[MyLocalMusicLibrary getAllTracks] compatiblePresets (
AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A,
AVAssetExportPreset960x540,
AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality,
AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality,
AVAssetExportPreset640x480,
AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality,
AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
)

 -[MyLocalMusicLibrary getAllTracks] export Session AVAssetExportSession: 0x1e85c0, 
asset = AVURLAsset: 0x1dd5a0, URL = ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=-212958261728896866, 
presetName = AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A, outputFileType = com.apple.m4a-audio

 -[MyLocalMusicLibrary getAllTracks] Export Status 4 Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain 
Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" 
UserInfo=0x1edfa0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12124), 
NSUnderlyingError=0x1ebdc0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -12124.)", 
NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

How can i fix this four errors. Do i need for this export the AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter.

Comment: Hey, did you solve this by any chance?

Comment: see link It may be helpful to you .Link:https://gist.github.com/1396335

Answer (score 8):

I got the same result from `AVAssetExportSession`, what the completely useless `NSError` is trying to tell you is that the path you're exporting to doesn't fully exist.  You'll want to make sure that you create the path to the directory you're placing the file in using `NSFileManager`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was that I was trying to convert the file directly from the tmp directory after getting it from the UIImagePickerController

What I had to do was first save the file to the Library, then iterate over the ALAssetLibrary files to find the latest video saved. Then I converted that video to .mp4 and stored it int he application's local documents directory for use as I please.

Kind of ridiculous that this is necessary but it works.